# Can "が" ever mark the direct object?

Tags: particle-が, particle-を, relative-clauses

A sentence in my book:

> これは、漢字{かんじ}**が**持{も}つ体系的{たいけいてき}なつながりを明{あき}らかにして文化勲章{ぶんかくんしょう}を受{う}けた漢字学{かんじがく}の第一人者{だいいちにんしゃ}、 白川{しらかわ}静{しずか}さんに、漢字の成{な}り立{た}ちを一つ{ひとつ}一つ{ひとつ}教{おし}えてもらった本{ほん}です。

The very start of the sentence reads: *"これは、漢字 **が** 持つ...."*

Why is the 助詞 "が" instead of " **を** "?
Isn't "漢字" the direct object of "持つ"?

Comment: No. 漢字が体系的なつながりを持つ -> 漢字が持つ体系的なつながり

Comment: @YangMuye I'm not getting it. You're saying that the object of "持つ" is "つながり". So, just to be clear, in textbooks, it is sometimes ok to place a verb before its object? wow. I did not know that. please confirm.

Comment: It can easily be argued that the answer to 'Can が ever mark a direct object?' is 'yes' (see [*The Oxford Handbook of Japanese Linguistics*, pages 141-155](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=4CS07LRO8O8C&pg=PA141)), but I don't think that's really relevant to your example sentence.  I think the problem you're having here is parsing the sentence properly.

Comment: @snailboat That first が coupled with no other option (I had thought) for 持つ's object definitely stops me from tokenizing. I can infer much of the meaning, but all those 助詞 are not adding up. As a start, I just want to understand the very start. I'll do the rest of the work. Just, what;s going on with "漢字が持つ"...

Comment: Do you know why this sentence uses 教えてもらった at the end instead of just 教えた?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

漢字が持つ is a relative clause.  It has a gap in object position:

> 漢字-が　＿＿-<strike>を</strike>　持つ

The gap is filled semantically by the following noun phrase 体系的なつながり:

> ①　​ 　漢字-が　体系的なつながり-を　持つ　　
>   ②　[　漢字-が　＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿-<strike>を</strike>　持つ　]　体系的なつながり

These can be translated into English:

> ①　Kanji have a systematic relationship.
>   ②　the systematic relationship　[　*which* kanji have ＿＿　]

The details are different in English because of articles and relative pronouns, but hopefully you can see the parallel:

In example ① we have an independent clause (a complete sentence).

In example ② we come up with a noun phrase by **relativizing** the clause; we pull out one of the arguments and turn it into the head noun that the clause modifies.

Comment: I'm ignoring whether が would be replaced with は if example ① were really used as a complete sentence.  It's simpler theoretically to start with が, and we'd have to use が anyway in the relative clause, so I thought talking about は would be a distraction.

Comment: a "gap" in the sentence structure.... I find that so interesting and representative of the language. Even in formal writing, context based inference trumps sentence structure. I can only imagine how unnatural a legally binding document written in Japanese must sound. Anyway, thank you very much!

Comment: @natlang As demonstrated in snailboat's answer (in the third yellow box), essentially the same exact analysis works with English...